# How do I run a Jenkins job on a weekend, AFTER another job has completed?

Tags: jenkins, build, chron

I have a job in Jenkins that I only want to run on Saturday, but it must only be ran after another job is finished (this is a report job, so data must be in place).

I understand how to use the Jenkins con expressions, but can I chain that in sequence with another job?  The idea being once the first job is completed, the date is checked.  If it's Saturday, run the second job.

Can Jenkins do that, or is it something I need to write via a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jenkin's Flexible Publish Plugin to set conditional build step:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Flexible+Publish+Plugin

Comment: Cool. Could you please mark the question is answered